# Looping through Index and Match functions

Tags: vba, excel, indexing, match

I'm trying to match up values from my new document and extract corresponding data from my older document (the one I open in my code).  However, I'm having trouble looping through my columns in which I set the data to look for.  I want to find if cells **`I2`** & **`V2`** exist in Columns **I** and **V** of my old workbook.  Then I want it to move on to to the next line and check cells **`I3`** & **`V3`** and so on.

My Code is:

```
Sub BCReport()
Dim wbO As Workbook
Dim wsO As Worksheet
Dim wbJune As Workbook, wsJune As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range, myCPTRange As Range, myAllowedRange As Range
Dim JuneCPTRange As Range, JuneALLRange As Range, JuneMCPGRange As Range

Set wbO = ThisWorkbook
Set wsO = wbO.Sheets("Combined")

Set wbJune = Workbooks.Open("J:\Blue Cross 15_0615_P.xls")
Set wsJune = wbJune.Sheets("Combined")

Set myRange = wsO.Range("AI2:AI3000")
Set myCPTRange = wsO.Range("I2:I3000")
Set myAllowedRange = wsO.Range("V2:V3000")
Set JuneCPTRange = wsJune.Range("I2:I3000")
Set JuneALLRange = wsJune.Range("V2:V3000")
Set JuneMCPGRange = wsJune.Range("AI2:AI3000")

For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
    'For j = 1 To myRange.Columns.Count

    myRange.FormulaArray = _
    myRange.FormulaArray = _
   "=INDEX('[Blue Cross 15_0615_P.xls]Combined'!$AI$2:$AI$790,MATCH(myCPTRange(i, 1).Value&myAllowedRange(i, 1).Value,'[Blue Cross 15_0615_P.xls]Combined'!$I$2:$I$790&'[Blue Cross 15_0615_P.xls]Combined'!$V$2:$V$790,0))"

    'Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

I keep getting the error **"Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"**.

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: Can you debug and check which line is giving you error. I doubt its your formula.

Comment: 2 times `myRange.FormulaArray = _` seems to a bit too much

Comment: It is the formula, It runs fine until I try and loop through the cells to look at, and for the FormulaArray, I tried myRange.test but that's generating an error too

Comment: whats the purpose of writing vba, I think you dont need its, by one formula I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I recorded a macro to produce exactly what you were trying to do and I found that it gave me R1C1 notation to make the array formula.

Replace this part of the code:

```
For i = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
    'For j = 1 To myRange.Columns.Count

    myRange.FormulaArray = _
    myRange.FormulaArray = _
   "=INDEX('[Blue Cross 15_0615_P.xls]Combined'!$AI$2:$AI$790,MATCH(myCPTRange(i, 1).Value&myAllowedRange(i, 1).Value,'[Blue Cross 15_0615_P.xls]Combined'!$I$2:$I$790&'[Blue Cross 15_0615_P.xls]Combined'!$V$2:$V$790,0))"

    'Next j
Next i
```

With this

```
With myRange

    .FormulaArray = "=INDEX('[Blue Cross 15_0615_P.xls]Combined'!C,MATCH(RC[-26]&RC[-13],'[Blue Cross 15_0615_P.xls]Combined'!C[-26]&'[Blue Cross 15_0615_P.xls]Combined'!C[-13],0))"        
End With
```

And see if it works. Bear in mind this takes the looping out of the code and puts the formula (and result) directly into the cells in column AI of the *Combined.xls* sheet. It also looks at the entire column set in each sheet, so if you have data after cell 790, you'll need to adjust for that.